# Android: Setting Action Bar Background Color

Tags: android

I know there are plenty of questions about this but I can't figure out what's wrong with my styles.

This is in my manifest:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

And in values\styles.xml, I have (EDIT, as per answers below, I moved the color to a resource).

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And added a res/values/color.xml file, which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

If I change the first style's line to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

This does reflect and turns the bar dark.

Why is my action bar not getting set to white?

Edit 1: If it helps, my minSdkVersion is 16 and my targetSdkVersion is 21.

Comment: I guess you have values-v11, values-v14, values-v21 folders too. If those, please changes them too.

Comment: This link will tell you how http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Comment: Just updated based off that and updated the question with what I added - still didn't change to white, and there is just one values folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was what you need:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_color_Primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/app_color_accent</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: You are correct - the color primary is what set the action bar color. Any idea if this is something for newer APIs only?

Comment: No, these codes are for compatibility. Only, if your device's Android system is higher than 20, some effects, take `colorPrimaryDark` for example, will display, or, they will not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item> 
</style>
```

the `android:background` attribute ONLY takes reference value, you are inserting raw color value, so it is ignored. Create a color resource instead and point to that resource like this 
`<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background color of your ActionBar dynamically as well. Example:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));
```

Note: I have already created a new file called color.xml in values/ and defined a color value for tag 'green' like:

```
<color name="green">#8CBE41</color>
```

Hope it will help.